# How to set up a Selenium Grid on Windows - as a "service"

Tags: java, windows, selenium

i read much about setting up selenium grid. the problem is that running many consoles within a user session is not an option for me. i need the grid to run as a service. because of that i tried jenkins selenium grid plugin but failed[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9567682/how-to-set-up-selenium-with-chromedriver-on-jenkins-hosted-grid).
Is there probably another solution to deploy the grid (the hub and each node) in a running webserver or as standalone service? (in my dreams there is a nice webbased gui to control the grid.)

Answer (score 1):

I've used [jsl](http://jslwin.sourceforge.net/) with success. I could not get [YAJSW](http://yajsw.sourceforge.net/) to work - kept complaining about missing privileges. There are some commercial alternatives like [AlwaysUp](http://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/) and [JSW](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp).

Every time I've had to run a Java application as a Windows Service I'm reminded how horrible this process is.

Answer (score 0):

i externalized this task and got a working solution that uses [Apache Commons Daemon](http://commons.apache.org/daemon/). The result looks like the tomcat bin/folder:

i got (each for hub and node): selenium_node.exe, selenium_nodew.exe, selenium_node_service_install.cmd, selenium_node_service_remove.cmd

great, isn't it? :-)